# "He has all of his goals achieved" or "He achieved all of his goals"?

Tags: sentence-usage

Which one of the following two sentences is more authentic English?

1) He has all of his goals achieved.

2) He achieved all of his goals.

Comment: What do you mean by "authentic"? Both are correct, but they mean different things.

Comment: Probably "idiomatic" is the intended word. @EsotericScreenName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further context, what you want is either

> He achieved all of his goals *or*
>   He has achieved all of his goals.

The construction with the participle at the end, however, is good English: it signifies that his goals are "in an achieved ". This construction is typically used in temporal references, designating a point in time when one stage of effort is complete:

> We cannot move forward until we have this report fully drafted. ... *that is, until the time when we have a fully drafted report in hand*
>   Don't start frying until you have all the cutlets breaded; you will want to move them in and out of the pan very quickly.

So your example would typically be used in something like this:

> Now that he has all of his goals achieved he must formulate new ones.